# Edit spreadsheet object in Word document with protection

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, spreadsheet, protected-mode

I am trying to create a template in Word to be used on a SharePoint site. Using Word 2003, is there a way to enable protection on a document that has an Excel Spreadsheet (97-2003) object on it but allow the spreadsheet object to be edited?

When I add the object as an exception, Word behaves as if the object were a picture. I understand why, but in un-protected mode, when the user double clicks on the object, it becomes a full blown, editable spreadsheet again.

Is it possible to allow the same functionality in protected mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run some tests and confirmed that you can add the Excel object as an exception and have it work the way you want it to.

Ensure that when you paste the cells into the Word document, you select one of the options that "...Links to Excel". After you've completed that, protect the document and add the entire table as an exception that everyone can edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier way:

Insert a continuous break before and after the inserted table.

Then, in `Restrict Editing`, part 2, `Editing Restrictions`; select `Filling in Forms`. Once the `Select sections` link is visible; click it and deselect the section that contains your table.